# How can I access files (images) in an azureml FileDataSet?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I have uploaded a big (10+gb) dataset into Azure Blob Storage, containing thousands of images (jpg) format.
I registered the blob container in Azure Machine Learning Service as a data store and I also registered a File Dataset, pointing to the actual blob container, containing the images. (showing there are 44440 images).

Now, I want to run a notebook (in AzureML) that needs to read a specific image and load it into an image (using `cv2.imread()`).  However, I don't seem to find the right documentation for this...  The only option I see is to download the entire dataset onto the local temp storage, which I prefer not to do (multiple giga bytes).

Is there an option I can use to access the actual file reference and pass it to my 3rd party method?

Below you can find some code that is relevant:

```py
# get workspace and datastore
ws = Workspace.from_config()
dstore = ws.datastores[datastore_name]
image_dataset = ws.datasets[image_dataset_name]

mounted_images = image_dataset.mount() 

img = cv2.imread(mounted_images['my_file_name.jpg']) # this will not work
```

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dataset.mount() actually returns a MountContext which has a mount_point attribute.

So:

img = cv2.imread(mounted_images.mount_point +’/my_file_name.jpg')

Should hopefully work.

Comment: Hello Daniel.  Thanks for your answer. 
It does not seem to work, though I might missing something.
When executing the following code, I can see the first file name listed, but when just trying to access that file, I get a FileNotFoundError (No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpoh3vd_pr/10000.jpg') 
`print(image_dataset.to_path()[0])  # outputs /10000.jpg`
`print(os.path.getsize(mounted_images.mount_point + '/10000.jpg'))`

Comment: another thing I was missingI had to execute  
  
`mounted_images.start()` before accessing it

Answer (score 3):

An extra note on Daniel's answer. When you mount a dataset, you attach the files referenced by the dataset to a directory (mount point) and make it available on the compute target. Mounting action itself is almost instant, and it will only load the part of data used by your script ('my_file_name.jpg' in your case) at the time of processing.

Answer (score 2):

Try the mount_text in this way

```
with dataset.mount() as mount_context:
    print(os.listdir(mount_context.mount_point))
```

Here I have mounted 10k high res images.

[image]

```
%%time
with dataset.mount() as mount_context:
    print(os.listdir(mount_context.mount_point))
```