# How to get AmlDatastore image url from Azure

Tags: azure, automl

I'm trying to use auto ML to train an object detection model. I have all of my images uploaded to azure and am trying to create my jsonl file for the tabular dataset. I'm using this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-auto-train-image-models

This is their example of an image url: AmlDatastore://image_data/Image_01.png

How do I get that url for my images in my datastore? When I view the image in the datastore, it shows me an https url. I tried using that one but I get an error that the file is not found. I've also tried making an AmlDatastore url with a path to my image with no luck there either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access files (images) in an azureml FileDataSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151965/how-can-i-access-files-images-in-an-azureml-filedataset)

Comment: `"image_url": "AmlDatastore://" + workspaceblobstore + "/" + os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(src)) + "/"` via [Automated Machine learning for Vision](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/automated-machine-learning-for-vision-5cad3b25759f)